# Angular HttpClient sending multiple requests to backend

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, httpclient, angularfire2

My code seems to be sending multiple requests to the server and caching the previously sent one. Not quite sure why this is but here is the code -

```
async onSubmit() {

    let formData =
      {
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
        gender: this.gender,
        dateOfBirth: this.dateOfBirth
      };

    let url = 'ip';

    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if (data && data.email && data.getIdToken(true).then((idToken) => {

        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': idToken
          })
        };

        this.http.post(url, formData, httpOptions)
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data;
          }, error => {
            console.log(error);// Error getting the data
          });

      }))
        window.alert("You have been registered.");
    })

  }
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Hard to say without a [mcve]. Is `this.afAuth.authState` emitting multiple values? Each one would trigger a new request. Or is `onSubmit` being called more than once? Try putting in some `console.log`s to see where it gets to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. It was sending multiple requests as it was an async function. Removing the async keyword fixed it.